# Using reflect, how to set value to a struct field (pointer)

Tags: go, reflect

I try to set  value to  a struct field (pointer field) by reflect, but  failed.

1. I get the name of a struct field,  so use FieldByName to get the field
2. The field is a pointer.
3. I try to use FieldByName().Set  FieldByName().SetPointer to set value.

```golang
type t struct {
    b *int
}

func main() {
    t := new(ts)
    a := new(int)
    ss := reflect.ValueOf(t).FieldByName("b").Set(a)
}
```

```golang
type t struct {
    b *int
}

func main() {
    t := new(ts)
    a := new(int)
    ss := reflect.ValueOf(t).FieldByName("b").SetPointer(a)
}
```

First code:
=======>
./test.go:14:50: cannot use a (type *int) as type reflect.Value in argument to reflect.ValueOf(t).FieldByName("b").Set
./test.go:14:50: reflect.ValueOf(t).FieldByName("b").Set(a) used as value

Second code:
=======>
./test.go:14:57: cannot use a (type *int) as type unsafe.Pointer in argument to reflect.ValueOf(t).FieldByName("b").SetPointer
./test.go:14:57: reflect.ValueOf(t).FieldByName("b").SetPointer(a) used as value

I want to use reflect to make  the pointer field (name "b")  alloced a space and set a value.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works.

Answer (score 7):

```
type ts struct {
    B *int    //field must be exported
}

func main() {
    var t ts
    foo := 5
    a := &foo
    //Use Elem() to indirect through the pointer and get struct field
    //Use reflect.ValueOf(a) to satisfy Set() signature
    reflect.ValueOf(&t).Elem().FieldByName("B").Set(reflect.ValueOf(a))
    fmt.Println(*t.B)
}
```

Playground https://play.golang.org/p/gZt0ahTZMIi

Comment: Just FYI, `Elem` does not "achieve setability", calling Elem on a non-settable value will not make it settable. Instead, in this case, Elem returns the `reflect.Value` representation of the *struct* value pointed to by `&t`. This is necessary because calling `FieldByName` on a `reflect.Value` representation of a *pointer* will panic since pointers do not have fields.